# Tailwind CSS No Utility Classes Were Found

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Trying to get Tailwind to work via CLI instructions [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation). I've got a (simplified) file structure of

```
-public 
  -stylesheets
    -styles.css
    -tailwind.css
-views
  -index
    -index.pug
    -page2.pug
    -page3.pug
  -user
    -index.pug
    -page2.pug
  -includes
    -templates
      -header.pug
      -footer.pug
```

I've followed the installation docs and a video on YouTube to try get it to work but when I set up `tailwind.config.js` with this :

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    '/views/**/*.pug'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

and try a simple test using Tailwind classes on `index/index.pug` like this :

```
extends ../index/layout

block content

  h1.text-3xl
    | Hello world!
```

and run `npx tailwindcss -i ./public/stylesheets/tailwind.css -o ./public/stylesheets/styles.css --watch`

I'm just getting a completely unformatted H1 on the frontend and a terminal warning of `warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the content option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Tailwind config file, your template path is listed as `'/views/**/*.pug'`.

The specified path starts at the root of your filesystem and not relative to the folder you're running the command from.

Update the path to `'./views/**/*.pug'`